# Populate Dropdown list appears empty

Tags: php

I appreciate the help everyone has been giving Me. I now have the dropdown box seemingly changing, however it is blank. The current coding I'm using is edited below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="EDIT" /><input type="hidden" name="Selection"  id="Selection" value="-1"><div>Below is the list of your saved codes. To edit your codes, select it from the list.</div>
<select> 
<?php 
$directory = realpath(dirname(FILE)) . '/../users/' . $_SESSION['username']; 

$files = scandir( $directory ) ;

foreach( $files as $file )
{
if ( ! is_dir( $file ) )
{
    echo "<option>" . $file . "</option>";
}
}
?>
</select>
```

When I inspect the empty dropdown element on the page I get this:

Warning:  scandir(/home/revo/public_html/evo/../users/Addiction) [function.scandir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/codesaveindex.php on line 117

Warning:  scandir() [function.scandir]: (errno 2): No such file or directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/codesaveindex.php on line 117

Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/revo/public_html/evo/codesaveindex.php on line 119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work replace **DIR** with the path that you want

```
<select> 
<?php

$directory = __DIR__;

$files = scandir( $directory ) ;

foreach( $files as $file )
{
    if ( ! is_dir( $file ) )
    {
        echo "<option>" . $file . "</option>";
    }
}
?>

</select>
```

Comment: Thank you yassine. This changed the dropdown list but it appears blank and I'm not sure if I'm writing the directory and everything else right.

Comment: <select> 
<?php

$directory = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../users/' . $_SESSION['username'];

$files = scandir( $directory ) ;

foreach( $files as $file )
{
    if ( ! is_dir( $file ) )
    {
        echo "<option>" . $file . "</option>";
    }
}
?>

</select>

Comment: when Inspect the dropdown element it returns this:  

Warning:  scandir(/home/revo/public_html/evo/../users/Addiction) [function.scandir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/codesaveindex.php on line 117

Warning:  scandir() [function.scandir]: (errno 2): No such file or directory in /home/revo/public_html/evo/codesaveindex.php on line 117

Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/revo/public_html/evo/codesaveindex.php on line 119

Comment: You have to make sure that you have a valid path, you can implement a check to see if the directory exists and not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you output a `<select>` tag, then you begin to build a php variable `$Selection` with concatenation (which is wrong since you never initialize the variable before concatenation).

See if this works:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="EDIT" /><input type="hidden" name="Selection"  id="Selection" value="-1"><div>Below is the list of your saved codes. To edit your codes, select it from the list.</div>
<?php

// match all files that have .txt extension
$file_matcher = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../users/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '/*.{txt}';

//Initialize variable $Selection
$Selection = '<select size="1" name="CodeList" id="CodeList" onchange="CodeChange();"><option value="0">(Add New Code)</option>';

foreach( glob($file_matcher, GLOB_BRACE) as $file ) {
    $file_name = basename($file);
    //Concatenate variable $Selection
    $Selection .= "<option value='$file'>$file_name</option>\n";
}

//Finish HTML source concatenation on $Selection
$Selection .= '</select>';

//Output the HTML
echo $Selection;
?>
```

Comment: I missed that select tag, thank you for the updates. However when I put that in and try and load the page it comes back with this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/revo/public_html/evo/codesaveindex.php on line 145

Comment: I wasn't quite sure I wrote that right, thank you. It saves the file, as it should, however the dropdown menu when the page loads is still blank and isn't populating. I'm unsure if I'm redirecting back to the page wrong after the save script is ran or something else is going on. When I inspect element on the page it throws the error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL , codesaveindex.php: 21

Comment: That line is much above last error, can you output the original php source please ?

Comment: have all of that fixed and redirect fixed, no seeming errors, its just not populating the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a somewhat complicated directory path.

```
$file_matcher = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/../users/' . $_SESSION['username'] . '/*.{txt}';
```

If the directory is not valid, you will not find any files and will not have a populated select.

Just for sake of testing, try a simple directory - without any vars - and see if it works. I'll bet that after Niloct's assistance, it will. +1 to Niloct.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance I had a feeling it might be in the directory I'm just not sure how to write it to find the correct directory that I need which should be users/$_SESSION['username'] I keep getting syntax or parsing errors.

Comment: Don't worry about that yet. Divide and conquer. First, get it populating the drop-down box with any file names at all. THEN, accept Niloct's answer and post a new question for assistance with the path navigation.

Comment: Got it. Doing just that. I got it to pop using just the Dir command he had up there. will post another question and accept his about directory filepath. Thank you!

Comment: Best wishes on your project. *May the road rise to meet you...*